# Laravel trying to get data from the pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-blade

im trying to get the data linked to my model out of the pivot table (many to many relationship).
i put customers on a many to many relationship with departments.

the migration:

```
Schema::create('customer_department', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('customer_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('customers');

            $table->foreign('department_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('departments');
        });
```

the customer model:

```
public function department(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department');
}
```

the department model:

```
public function customer(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Customer');
}
```

now im trying to print out every department the customer is assigned to in the view. i tried

```
{{$customer->department}}
or
@foreach($customer->department as $depo)
{{$depo->name}}
@endforeach
or
{{$customer->pivot->department_id}}
...
```

the controller:

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
    {
        return view('/customers/customer', ['customer' => $customer]);
    }
```

however i get several error messages, empty arrays or straightup nothing. what am i doing wrong? what did i forget?

Comment: how did you retrieve this `$customer` record?

Comment: i added the controller function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the model retrieved via the Many to Many relationship for it to have this attached `pivot` model. `$customer` would not have this `pivot` but everything returned from `$customer->department` would have these `pivot` models attached:

```
@foreach ($customer->department as $department)
    {{ $department->pivot->department_id }}
@endforeach
```

Though, in this case you don't need to involve the pivot model since you want information from the Department models:

```
@foreach ($customer->department as $department)
    {{ $department->getKey() }}
    {{ $department->name }}
@endforeach
```

It would be a good idea to name these relationships in the plural since they return many, not in the singular.

Comment: works like a charm, since i want to print out the name instead of ->department_id i did ->name. thanks :D:D